# Google Maps not loading points from a mysql database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm following [this](http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/10/google-map-v3-editing-saving-marker-in-database) tutorial on placing markers on a google maps through a form window and saving them to a database. Everything is working fine however, the map is not loading the markers from the database when it loads up. 
In my main.php file (with all the html) I have this function running to place markers on the map.

```
//############### Create Marker Function ##############
function create_marker(MapPos, MapTitle, MapDesc,  InfoOpenDefault, DragAble, Removable, iconPath)
{                 

    //new marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: MapPos,
        map: map,
        draggable:DragAble,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        title:"Hello World!",
        //icon: iconPath
    });

    //Content structure of info Window for the Markers
    var contentString = $('<div class="marker-info-win">'+
    '<div class="marker-inner-win"><span class="info-content">'+
    '<h1 class="marker-heading">'+MapTitle+'</h1>'+
    MapDesc+ 
    '</span><button name="remove-marker" class="remove-marker" title="Remove Marker">Remove Marker</button>'+
    '</div></div>');    


    //Create an infoWindow
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    //set the content of infoWindow
    infowindow.setContent(contentString[0]);

    //Find remove button in infoWindow
    var removeBtn   = contentString.find('button.remove-marker')[0];
    var saveBtn     = contentString.find('button.save-marker')[0];

    //add click listner to remove marker button
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(removeBtn, "click", function(event) {
        remove_marker(marker);
    });

    if(typeof saveBtn !== 'undefined') //continue only when save button is present
    {
        //add click listner to save marker button
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(saveBtn, "click", function(event) {
            var mReplace = contentString.find('span.info-content'); //html to be replaced after success
            var mName = contentString.find('input.save-name')[0].value; //name input field value
            var mDesc  = contentString.find('textarea.save-desc')[0].value; //description input field value
            var mType = contentString.find('select.save-type')[0].value; //type of marker

            if(mName =='' || mDesc =='')
            {
                alert("Please enter Name and Description!");
            }else{
                save_marker(marker, mName, mDesc, mType, mReplace); //call save marker function
            }
        });
    }

    //add click listner to save marker button        
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,marker); // click on marker opens info window 
    });

    if(InfoOpenDefault) //whether info window should be open by default
    {
      infowindow.open(map,marker);
    }
}
```

And in my map_process.php file (the file that deals with the db requests.) 
I have this:

```
<?php
//PHP 5 +

// database settings 
$db_username = 'user4321';
$db_password = '4321';
$db_name = 'test';
$db_host = 'localhost';

//mysqli
$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) 
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not connect to db!'); 
    exit();
}

################ Save & delete markers #################
if($_POST) //run only if there's a post data
{
    //make sure request is comming from Ajax
    $xhr = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest'; 
    if (!$xhr){ 
        header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Request must come from Ajax!'); 
        exit(); 
    }

    // get marker position and split it for database
    $mLatLang   = explode(',',$_POST["latlang"]);
    $mLat       = filter_var($mLatLang[0], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);
    $mLng       = filter_var($mLatLang[1], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT);

    //Delete Marker
    if(isset($_POST["del"]) && $_POST["del"]==true)
    {
        $results = $mysqli->query("DELETE FROM markers WHERE lat=$mLat AND lng=$mLng");
        if (!$results) {  
          header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not delete Markers!'); 
          exit();
        } 
        exit("Done!");
    }

    $mName      = filter_var($_POST["name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $mAddress   = filter_var($_POST["address"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $mType      = filter_var($_POST["type"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    $results = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO markers (name, address, lat, lng, type) VALUES ('$mName','$mAddress',$mLat, $mLng, '$mType')");
    if (!$results) {  
          header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not create marker!'); 
          exit();
    } 

    $output = '<h1 class="marker-heading">'.$mName.'</h1><p>'.$mAddress.'</p>';
    exit($output);
}


################ Continue generating Map XML #################

//Create a new DOMDocument object
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers"); //Create new element node
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node); //make the node show up 

// Select all the rows in the markers table
$results = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1");
if (!$results) {  
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Error: Could not get markers!'); 
    //console.log("This an error");
    exit();
} 

//set document header to text/xml
header("Content-type: text/xml"); 

// Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
while($obj = $results->fetch_object())
{
  $node = $dom->createElement("marker");  
  $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);   
  $newnode->setAttribute("name",$obj->name);
  $newnode->setAttribute("address", $obj->address);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $obj->lat);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $obj->lng);  
  $newnode->setAttribute("type", $obj->type);   
}

echo $dom->saveXML();

?>
```

Now I can't seem to find the source of why this isn't loading the markers in the first place. Is any of the above code incorrect, considering I have all the other namings correct.

edit: I'm getting a 500 (internal server error) in console, but I can't see this being the problem as I have another map which I am testing which correctly loads saved points. 
The format of is `'GET' serveraddress/mapprocess.php (500 internal server error)`. Not sure if this helps at all but upon saving a marker (which is does successfully) I get `XHR finished loading: GET "severaddress/mapprocess.php"` as a response.

Any ideas of why this wouldn't load the markers. Or where exactly I should be looking.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1` ?

Comment: @charlietfl got rid of the where 1,  still the same error.

Comment: 1. how does your page load the XML? 2. What does the XML look like?  3. Is the XML created by map_process.php valid?

Comment: Remove comma from `title:"Hello World!",`

Comment: I worked out the problem, It had something to do with the mixture of connections between mysql and mysqli calls. Just kept to it to one type and all up and going.

Answer (score 0):

I know it might be late but the reason its not working is because the data i.e longitude and latitude being returned from mysql might be in string format and the google maps api expects float values for longitude and latitude hence convert the received values to float using parseFloat() in Javascript.